# Related to useEffect function using despatch as dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
import { Stack, Typography } from "@mui/material";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { FetchQuestions } from "../Actions/User";

const Homepage = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { question_set_self_created } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch quiz questions when the component mounts
    dispatch(FetchQuestions("self_created"));
   
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <div className="Homepage">
      <Typography>
        Hello quizzers. Select the quiz you want to take below
      </Typography>
      <Stack
        gap={2}
        sx={{
          width: "40vw",
          height: "30vh",
          boxShadow: "4px 4px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)",
          borderRadius: "8px",
          padding: "16px",
          cursor: "Pointer"
        }}
      >
        {/* Render quiz information based on question_set_self_created */}
        {question_set_self_created.map((quiz, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <Typography variant="h5">Quiz Subject: {quiz.quiz_subject}</Typography>
            <Typography variant="h5">Duration: {quiz.quiz_duration} minutes</Typography>
            <Typography variant="h5">Number of Questions: {quiz.quiz_no_of_questions}</Typography>
            {/* Render individual quiz questions */}
            {/* {quiz.quiz_data.map((question, qIndex) => (
              <div key={qIndex}>
                <Typography variant="subtitle1">Question {qIndex + 1}: {question.questionText}</Typography>
                <Typography variant="body1">Options:</Typography>
                <ul>
                  {question.options.map((option, oIndex) => (
                    <li key={oIndex}>
                      {option.optionText} {option.isCorrect ? "(Correct)" : ""}
                    </li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </div>
            ))} */}
          </div>
        ))}
      </Stack>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Homepage;
```

This code takes a set of quizzes from mongodb database and shows the quizzes to the client. This code is working fine but I am not sure how does it work.
 When I tried to call the dispacth FetchQuestions function without using the useEffect hook, it ran infinitely. But this code only runs once.
 Why in this code useEffect code is even working when the function to change the dispatch dependency is inside the useEffect function.
 Even if it is working, how the value of question_set_self_created is changing after the fetchQuestions dispatch is called. Because the value of the state should change and not the value of the data created using that state.
 I think this code is rendered again after the FetchQuestion function is called and its action is completed(taking request from the backend and updating the value in the state), but i am not sure why no time lag issue is occuring here

Answer (score 0):

There is no time lag issue because React's rendering and reconciliation process handles updates efficiently. The component re-renders with the new state after the action is completed. React's virtual DOM diffing algorithm determines the minimal changes needed to update the actual DOM, and it does this in an optimized way.

In summary, the useEffect hook with its dependency array ensures that the fetching action is only triggered once when the component mounts. Subsequent state changes due to the action's completion trigger re-renders of the component, efficiently updating the UI to reflect the updated state.